# Current draw of an Arc Lighter

Tags: resistance, lighting, arc

I have an arc lighter, similar to that which you can see here:

[image: arch lighter]

My question is this. I understand that you need a very high voltage, created by a transformer within the device, to create sufficient potential difference for the air between the elecrodes to break down, and ionise, and therefore allow current to flow in the form of a plasma. Once the arc is established, if the resistance is low, why does the current not jump up to levels that would drain a small lithium ion battery extremely quickly? If I = V/R does is the plasma resistance still fairly high?

Comment: If it resembles a certain kind of welder it likely has an intermediary bank that it charges to high voltages.  When the arc is established, it only drains that bank, dropping it to a low voltage very quickly.   The battery only "charges" the bank.  Such a bank could be created with energy storing components -inductors (or even capacitors if you opt for a charge in parallel discharge in series methodology)

Comment: Similar to luminescent lights. To start 600V, work 60V. It is an arc inside tube.

Comment: Perhaps they use the CCFL-driver trick:  place a low-value capacitor in series with the arc, then drive the arc with high-freq AC.  The capacitor presents a series impedance, functioning as a "ballast resistor" to limit arc-current, while ideally having zero loss.

Comment: Here's a teardown by BigClive. Schematic and explanation included. :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aK1GK1KBGc

Answer (score 2):

To make a paper-napkin calculation, consider the energy to charge and discharge the battery.

> "Recharge your USB electric lighter over and over again within a couple of hours with a USB cable. When charged, your plasma lighter can be used around 300-500 times before you need to recharge it."  [REF](https://www.groovyguygifts.com/blogs/news/electric-lighter)

USB cable 10W or 12W x 2 h= 24Wh x 60s /400 times per charge avg. = 3.6 Watt-seconds / light for 1 second from 3.6V = 1Amp per light to ignite the arc at 2kV/mm gap which drops to low voltage and high current from some DC-DC converter at 1W and unknown V or I **perhaps a 30V @ 66 mA  more or less for 1/2 s light time.**

Answer (score 1):

Because the voltage almost certainly isn't constant.

I don't know the details of how those things are designed, but if there's a transformer involved it's pretty easy to make a fairly constant-current device (old-style stick welders did this with a transformer designed to have a lot of leakage inductance).  With a modest (by today's standards) amount of electronics, making a constant-power driver is easy, too.